# DE manipulation in Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio

I'm trying to write a SSJS script in Automation Studio. I want to retrieve column values from one DE, clear that table, and write that column data to another one. (Among other things.) In a prior step, a CSV is imported to a table (SampleDE1.)

**Retrieve data:**

```
var holdingTank = DataExtension.Init("SampleDE1");
var filter = {SortOrder:1};
var data = holdingTank.Rows.Retrieve(filter);

var column1val = data[0].column1;
var column2val = data[0].column2;
```

**Clear table:**

```
holdingTank.Rows.Remove(["column1", column1val]);
```

This is where I am at so far, but it's not working. No records are being removed, there are no errors, and the automation says it's a success. What's going on? There is no console or any way to debug this that I'm aware of.

I'm referring to this page: [**Data Extension Server-Side JavaScript Functions**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/data_extension_server_side_javascript_functions/)

*If for some reason these functions aren't supported in automation scripts, this'll be the second major roadblock to my project success placed by SalesForce.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check your brackets in your `Rows.Remove()`.  I pulled this from a Script Activity that I'm using to delete rows from a DE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">

Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

// other code sets jobID
var jobID = "123";

var sl = DataExtension.Init("SendLog");
var delCount = 0;

try {

    delCount = sl.Rows.Remove(["JobID"], [jobID]);
    Write(delCount);

} catch (e) {

    Write(e);

}

</script>
```

Comment: Hm. I did essentially exactly what you did, to no effect. Also, does **e** show up anywhere for you? Error logs would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: SFMC Support has access to the logs, but I've found that more trouble than it's worth.  I typically write to a log DE in the `catch` or display them (in some scenarios)

Comment: They do seem sensitive about those. :) After getting on the line w/ them, it turned out to be an issue with the DE in question being in Shared Data Extensions. Prefacing the reference with "ENT." made it work.